# Primefaces Login Authentication Servlet Filter - can still access protected pages directly via their urls

Tags: java, servlets, primefaces, servlet-filters, basic-authentication

I have three primefaces (version 4.0) webpages. One of them is a login.xhtml which I want to use to authenticate a user before they are allowed to access either of the other two webpages. I am using Tomcat server (v7.0)

My problem is that I can access the login.xhtml from my base url: `http://localhost:8080/controlservice-server`/ --> which does the correct user authentication and then passes through onto the correct webpage.

However, I am able to access the other two webpages directly from their urls without having to go through the login page and therefore anyone can access them.

My web.xml:

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

<welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>Login.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

My Authentication Web Filter:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@WebFilter(filterName = "PrimefacesAuthFilter", urlPatterns={"*.Login.xhtml"})
public class PrimesfacesAuthFilter implements Filter {

  public PrimesfacesAuthFilter() {
  }

  @Override
  public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
  }

  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    try {

      HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
      HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
      HttpSession ses = req.getSession(false);

      String reqURI = req.getRequestURI();
      if (reqURI.indexOf("/*.xhtml") >= 0 || (ses != null && ses.getAttribute("username") != null)
          || reqURI.indexOf("/public/") >= 0 || reqURI.contains("javax.faces.resource")) {

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
      }
      else
        res.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/login.xhtml");
    } catch (Throwable t) {
      System.out.println(t.getMessage());
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void destroy() {

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change urlPatterns attribute in your @WebFilter annotation as below:

```
@WebFilter(filterName = "PrimefacesAuthFilter", urlPatterns={"*.xhtml"})
```